# How to pull a file (more than 64 kB) from Android device with C?

Tags: c

I am sending commands to adb server like `STAT` and `RECV` after converting into big endian format, but my code is not working for files larger than 64 kB? How to solve this problem?

Comment: If you provide your not-working code maybe someone can take a look at it and help you.

Comment: If the break-point is 64 KiB, then it is likely that something is using a 16-bit (unsigned) value which causes the size to 'wrap' back to zero when it gets bigger than 64 KiB.  Whether there is a resolution for this depends on what uses the 16-bit quantity.  If the network protocol format imposes a 16-bit number on the file size, then you're hosed until you use a different message or get the protocol revised.  If you're using a 16-bit number yourself, then change it to use a 32-bit number instead.